# Is metamizole associated with rebound headaches?

Tags: medications, headache, analgesics

I can't find any specific mention on the internet if Metamizole (most known as dipyrone) is specifically associated with rebound headaches like other pain relieve medications like Aspirin, Acetaminophen, etc?

Comment: It seems to be mainly a [veterinary medication](https://www.drugs.com/international/metamizole.html). A lot more research would improve your question.

Comment: I don't know about that. In my country is super common and widely used. So what exactly more i should research?

Comment: In some countries, this medicine may only be approved for veterinary use.

Also says "some". Not that is a exclusive veterinary medication

Comment: Metamizole is not mainly a veterinary medication. Its use may be limited in some countries, but this does not constitute the majority.

Comment: Regardless, the question could still use more research. Rebound headaches are also known as medication overuse headaches and are associated with most/all pain relievers used for headaches.

Comment: But I can't find anywhere specifically talking about metamizole/dyprone only other substances

Comment: @Freedo From what I've read it's not drug specific so it won't be any different than aspirin, acetaminophen, etc.